# Connecting to Zoom meeting in browser (not the Zoom app) results in error message: This meeting link is invalid (3,001)

Tags: macos, browser, zoom-meeting

I do *not* want to install the Zoom client app on my computer (macOS). I want to **connect to a meeting *via a web browser***.

I have a URL for a meeting in the form of:

```
https://zoom.us/j/some_nine_digit_number_here
```

Loading that URL in a browser brings me to a page offering to (1) launch the meeting in a Zoom client app, (2) download a Zoom client app, or (3) "Join from Your Browser".

[image: screenshot of Zoom.us site offering "Join from Your Browser" link]

Clicking that third option to join from a browser takes me to a page to enter my name and take a reCAPTCHA test. After passing the captcha test, I get an error message page saying:

> This meeting link is invalid (3,001)

[image: screenshot of error message]

I called a friend and asked him to try the same URL. He got the same problem.

Googling seems to show this is a common problem. But nowhere did I find a solution, nor an explanation.

I did see some suggestions that the [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)) browser is not compatible. So I tried the latest [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox), but got the same error message.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks for trying to improve the Question, but you made the images unreadable. I must do a rollback. I have already downsized the images to be <100k JPEG files.

Comment: “…but you made the images unreadable.” Fair criticism, but the full-sized screenshots take up so much real estate on a landscape oriented screen — desktop and laptop — the text that appears after and between the images might be missed. Also, are you going to `https://zoom.us/join`?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 True, but I first posted the Question without images and got an incorrect answer about how to install an app — despite the very first sentence saying I do *not* want to install an app. So I added the images expressly for those folks who do *not* read carefully.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I was given a URL in the form of `https://zoom.us/j/some_long_number_here`. I added that info to the Question; thanks for asking.

Comment: When you say `some_long_number_here` look at the careful. It is a standard web URL that contains the meeting number which is an 11 digit number for the meeting itself. The rest of the parameter *might* be the password encoded as a hash. But I believe you can test manually entering that ID into `https://zoom.us/join` or `https://zoom.us/j` which are effectively the same sites.

Comment: The URL has a nine-digit number. I assume that is not the problem as that first screenshot has the URL with `#success` appended. Presumably that means the number was valid.